# Sencha list scrolling with keyboard

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am using sencha list in my application. It is a scrollable list. I want to scroll the list by <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd> key and hand gesture in keyboard. Does anyone know how to do it?

Please help me.

This is my code:

```
{      
    xtype: 'list',
    pinHeaders: false,
    variableHeights: false,
    itemTpl:
            '<div>' +
            '<div>{name}</div>' +
            '</div>',
    store: 'myStore',
    grouped: true,
    onItemDisclosure: true
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain better what you need to do? It's not clear what you mean by "I want to scroll the list by up, down key and hand gesture in keyboard".

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/53t

You can add a document eventlistener on keydown event in your application launch function and then scroll by the height of your list item.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'slidelist'
        });
        document.addEventListener("keydown", Ext.bind(onBackKeyDown, this), false);
        function onBackKeyDown(e) {
            switch(e.keyIdentifier)
            {
                case "Up":
                    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('slidelist')[0].getScrollable().getScroller().scrollBy(0, -47);
                break;
                case "Down":
                    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('slidelist')[0].getScrollable().getScroller().scrollBy(0, 47);
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```