# Login in sencha touch 2 through go button of android phone

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How to call a function on the tap of the Go button present in smartphones in sencha touch 2 ?

Comment: Edit your question wit what you have tried so for. It will be useful for others to answer

Comment: Can you pls suggest something to try i do know how to take it forward..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to wire-up an an event listener in your application's launch function and then inspect the keyIdentifier.  You can look at similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154398/sencha-list-scrolling-with-keyboard/23085991#23085991)

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", Ext.bind(onKeyDown, this), false);
```